# Microsoft Office Windows 7 style on ubuntu (with Wine?)

Tags: wine

I am using Wine and Play on Linux to launch Microsoft Office applications.

I can change the button style to a seven-like style, but I wonder how they changed the border of the app in this video.

[Ubuntu tablet full video min. 5:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h384z7Ph0gU)

How to do it ?

Comment: That's not WinE in the video. I think that app is runing under a real Windows machine. The tab is capable of streaming the app to you. I don't think you can change the Windows borders of Wine apps, because those borders belong to compiz. Compiz doesn't facilitate unique Window border theming for apps.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean with Windows machine? Because they are under Ubuntu! Or do you mean that Windows is virtualized? What could they use?

Comment: The app is running on a a windows server and you get the window via some kind of vnc remote connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like GreyscaleImag3s and Naveen said, it probably isn't realy on Ubuntu, but just launched with vnc remote connection or whatever but it is not installed on Ubuntu.
thanks to  Naveen and GreyscaleImag3s for the help!